# unable to query Case object

Tags: soql, permissions

when trying to query case object with below SOQL, giving me an error that no such field exist. where as i can able to see field in the customization. ? is this permission issue ?

```
select id,status ,division from case
```

Answer (score 2):

Division is not a standard field, so you will need to find the API name for that field and then use that in your query.

1. Go to Setup|Customize|Cases|Fields
2. Find Division in the `Field Label` column. Use the value in the next column, `Field Name` for your query.

Example: If Division has a field name of Division__c, your SOQL would be:

```
SELECT Id, Status, Division__c FROM Case
```

**Alternative**:

You can use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) to help build SOQL and SOSL queries.

Comment: query given by you is working but when added new field recordtype is it not working ...select id,status ,Division__c,RecordType from case

Comment: Try using Workbench to get all of the proper field names. There's a link to it in my answer.